# Java Conditions Confusion? (Beginner)

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

The aim of this program is to make a Rock Paper Scissors game. I have succeeded in making it however I can not get it to loop no matter what I try. I tried:

```
while (index = 0)
while (index < gamesCount)
```

However, while my index is 0 and my condition says `while (index != 0)`, it seems to be the only condition that runs the program but it will not loop regardless. How can I get my game to loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RockPaperScissors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        //Variables
        String player1;
        int cpu;
        int start = 1;
        int end = 3;
        int index = 0;

        // 1 = Rock | 2 = Scissors | 3 = Paper
        //Code
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
        while (index != 0) {
            System.out.print("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?: ");
            player1 = in.nextLine();
            cpu = randomGen.nextInt(3);
            System.out.println(cpu);

            if (player1.equals("Rock") && (cpu == 2)) {
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
            } else if (player1.equals("Rock") && (cpu == 1)) {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
            } else if (player1.equals("Rock") && (cpu == 0)) {
                System.out.println("Draw!");
            }

            // --------------------

            if (player1.equals("Scissors") && (cpu == 2)) {
                    System.out.println("Draw!");
            } else if (player1.equals("Scissors") && (cpu == 1)) {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
            } else if (player1.equals("Scissors") && (cpu == 0)) {
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
            }

            //---------------------

            if (player1.equals("Paper") && (cpu == 2)) {
                    System.out.println("You lose!");
            } else if (player1.equals("Paper") && (cpu == 1)) {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
            } else if (player1.equals("Paper") && (cpu == 0)) {
                    System.out.println("Draw!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (index < gamesCount)` seems like a good option - why did it not do what you want?  If you use this approach, you would need to add one to (*increment*) the index on each loop (i.e. `index++` inside the loop) and then defined `gamesCount` to be the number of loops you want (e.g. `int gamesCount = 10;`)

Comment: P.S.  at the moment in your program, `index` is always zero, so `index != 0` will always be false, so the program will never enter that block of code.  When you were trying `while (index = 0)`, you probably meant `while(index == 0) - which would make the game loop infinitely at the moment.  You need to understand that `=` is the assignment operator (i.e. giving a variable a value) and `==` is the equality comparison operator (i.e. testing are two values the same) in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your index variable set to 0.  The condition of the while loop is saying, if index does not equal 0, execute the code in the loop.  Since your index equals 0, the instructions in the loop will not be executed.  Also, you will need to update the index variable in the loop so that if the condition you are looking for is met, the code will stop looping.
ie:

```
int gamesPlayed = 0;
int gamesRequested = 3; // or get this from the user

while (gamesPlayed < gamesRequested){
    String player1Choice = in.nextLine();
    if(!"".equals(player1)){
    // your code
        gamesPlayed++;
    } else {
        System.out.print("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I done this! Thanks! But the only problem now is when I run it and put in something like I want to play 3 games... the first time it asks for your option it says it twice "Rock, Paper or Scissors: Rock, Paper or Scissors: " <- These put together count as 2 games even though I can only enter once

Comment: When the player enters the number of games that they would like to play, your code then generates a random number and then prints it out.  That printout is being picked up by the Scanner and then your conditions are not being met, so the loop will execute again.  I would test the results of your scanner upon entering the loop to see if it has the value that you're looking for, and if not, then ask for Rock, Paper, or Scissors.  ie,         Something like the edited answer above...

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes:

`while (index != 0);`

this is the entire loop. it ends either at the end of the { } block (which you don't have), or at the first ; which is immediately after the statement.

Correct this, though, and it still won't loop:

```
int index = 0;

        // 1 = Rock | 2 = Scissors | 3 = Paper



        //Code
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
        while (index != 0);
```

index = 0, so (index != 0) will never return true.

Answer (score 1):

Your index variable is set to a value of 0.
Your while loop says

```
while (index != 0);
```

Which means, while the index isn't 0, run my code. The problem is your code will never run then because your index value is always 0.
Try changing it to another value (say 5 for example), and it should work now.

:)